# Problem adding text inside tags using createTextNode and createElement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add new text node and a new li element but the result is a new li empty tag and a new separated string.

The string should be inside the created li tag.

Maybe my question is easy to answer but I really still don't understand how can the a new string can be added inside a tag since they are separately inserted into the DOM.

Inspecting results

[image]

any ideas ?

The source code is below

```js
function Adding(){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('text').value;
    let t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(t);
    
}

let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', Adding)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

h1{
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    color: #96e5ff;

}

.title{
    display: block;
}

.form{
    display: block;
}

input{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px #d6eeff solid;
    

}

button{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: snow;
    border: solid 1px #d6eeff;

}

#list{
    padding: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px !important;
    background-color: snow;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #d6eeff solid 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>TODO List using JS</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form">
    <input id="text" placeholder="Add something" type="text">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">
        <li></li>
    </ul>


</body>

<script src="app.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Comment: You need to append the text node to the `<li>`, not to the `<ul>`

Comment: I've done so but now all inputs are being inserted inside one li element resulting one line output. how to output every input inside a separated li tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a textNode. Just set the `innerText` property on the `<li>` element you created, and append the `<li>` to the `<ul>` element.

```js
function Adding(){
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerText =  document.getElementById('text').value;
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    
}

let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', Adding)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

h1{
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    color: #96e5ff;

}

.title{
    display: block;
}

.form{
    display: block;
}

input{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px #d6eeff solid;
    

}

button{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: snow;
    border: solid 1px #d6eeff;

}

#list{
    padding: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px !important;
    background-color: snow;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #d6eeff solid 1px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0 auto
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>TODO List using JS</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form">
    <input id="text" placeholder="Add something" type="text">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="list">
        <li></li>
    </ul>


</body>

<script src="app.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your Javascript code in this way:

```
function Adding(){
    let ul = document.getElementById("list");
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let inputValue = document.getElementById('text').value;
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputValue));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```